# How to get mysql's edit (\e) feature to preserve formating on arbitrary lines

Tags: mysql, vim

When using the mysql command line client, I like to use \e (edit) to put the previous sql statement into Vim for editing. When I do this, it contains all the nice line breaks and indentations I added from the last time I edited the sql. However, I can only get this feature with the **very last** query that I entered. If I use the up arrow key to find the sql I want to edit in Vim, then re-enter it, then use \e, I *can* get it back in Vim, but all line breaks and indentation I used to format the sql are lost.

How can I get my previous sql back in Vim, along with its nicely formatted indentations and line breaks, even if it isn't the very last line in mysql's command history?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, executing queries from Vim instead of editing queries from `mysql`. There are quite a few plugins that help do this:

- [dbtext.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=356) - Provides database access to many DBMS (Oracle, Sybase, Microsoft, MySQL, DBI,..)
- [mysqlquery](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2081) - Simple and Easy to use utility for executing MySQL queries
- [vim-simpledb](https://github.com/ivalkeen/vim-simpledb) - Execution of postgresql or mysql commands from vim buffer
- [vim-pipe](https://github.com/krisajenkins/vim-pipe) - Send a vim buffer through a command and instantly see the output
- [clam.vim](https://github.com/sjl/clam.vim) - A lightweight Vim plugin for working with shell commands

Both vim-pipe and clam.vim run any shell command and are not limited to mysql in any way.

I made my own mysql runner, [Cupcake](https://gist.github.com/PeterRincker/b0d549fe97e202123e0a). However I never bothered packaging it up as a plugin as I found there where already many alternatives out there and it doesn't really add anything new.

Comment: I've been trying mysqlquery and I like it. The only downside I see so far is that you can't see the query and the resultset at the same time - like in separate, visible buffers (not that you could with \e). Either way, thanks, this is very useful.

Comment: I can't speak for the plugin as I do not use it. There are quite a few to choose from so pick one you like. I think a few of these should show the query results and your query in separate buffers. I know my "plugin" shows the results in the preview window for example.

Comment: 4 years later: I would go on to adopted dbext.vim, and I've never looked back. It allows you to execute your queries in a Vim window and see the results in another Vim window directly beneath. What more could you want, really?

Answer (score 0):

When composing complex queries in the MySQL client using vim vim `\e`, you can actually save different versions of the query via `:w foo`.

The file will be stored in the current directory (the directory you were in when you ran `mysql`). Though this will not let you edit any arbitrary previous query with formatting intact, it will let you save and edit **with formatting** various canonical queries from which you could continue evolving your final query. I personally find this limitation to be helpful as it helps me structure the direction in which I develop the query.